# Is it correct to say: I am with pain?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say: I am with pain?
thank you very much for your help

Comment: I had a surgery, and was asked how I felt. I answered: I am with pain. was I right?

Comment: None of the example sentences in [Oxford's definition of *pain*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pain) use *with:* they all use *in* as the preposition. Please be sure to research before asking questions; you will get the same answer far more quickly finding it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I think the phrase you're looking for is "I am **in pain**".

> **Be in pain**
>
> *If you are in pain, you feel pain in a part of your body, because you are injured or ill.*

[collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-in-pain)